# Android Broadcast Receiver when app is running in background

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

There have beed many questions similar to this but none of them adresses my problem (please, read whole question).

In my application I need to listen for ACCESSORY_DETTACHED intent action, but it should be handled only when app is running (in foreground or background) and NOT when app is not running.

I know there are 2 options. To register BroadcastReceiver in Manifest (won't work as I don't want onReceive to be called when my app is not running) or to register it in Activity (but then I'd have to unregister it somewhere to avoid leaks and I cannot do this in onStop as I need it to work in background as well and onDestroy is not recommended).

I figured out I could register receiver in Application class and it works, but still, I cannot unregister it anywhere. Does this approach lead to leaks? Should I even bother? Are there any other possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this approach lead to leaks?

That would depend upon your implementation of the custom `Application` subclass and the `BroadcastReceiver`.

You would not be leaking the receiver by calling `registerReceiver()` from the `onCreate()` method of your `Application`. We reserve the term "leak" for using memory when we do not want to, and you *want* the receiver to be working as long as  your process is alive.

However, the *receiver* might leak memory, depending on what it holds onto (if anything), as it will be around as long as your process is. Other stuff in your custom `Application` might be leaked, depending on what else you are doing in the `Application`.

So, your approach will not itself be a memory leak, but you will want to check your receiver and `Application` closely to make sure that you are not introducing other leaks along the way.

Comment: In both 'Application' and 'BroadcastReceiver' I've got only local variables in 'onCreate()' and 'onReceive()' so I guess I wouldn't leak anything there. Thank you!